# bootstrap 3.0 popover ('hide') method : not working with multiple popovers content and title not removed

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.0 to show  create popover for each event in #fullCalendar. below is the code for that.  inside eventAfterRender: function

```
element.popover({

title:'<b>Title :</b>'+ event.title,
placement: 'auto left',
container: 'body',
html:'true',
content:'<b>Start:</b> ' + event.start + '<br /> <b>End:</b> ' + event.end +'<br /><b>created by:</b> ' + event.username + '<br /><b>Description:</b> ' + event.description + '<br> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#taskEditDialouge" class="editEvent" id="EditEvent"  >Edit</a> </t></t> '    }
```

so the above code renders all the popover on calendar.

and below code is to hide popover

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
       if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
             element.popover('hide');
        });
```

but when i call hide method to hide the current popover and to show other one the below code is not escaping from the code  and due to that i am not able to use the other elements on the calendar behind this code.

```
<div class="popover fade left" style="top: 245px; left: 736px; display: block;" data-original-title="" title=""><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"><b>Title :</b>group task</h3><div class="popover-content"><b>Start:</b> Tue Nov 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)<br> <b>End:</b> null<br><b>created by:</b> x<br><b>Description:</b> <br> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#taskViewDialouge" class="viewEvent" id="ViewEvent:7231384945464">View</a>  <a data-toggle="modal" <a="" href="#" class="completeEvent" id="CompleteEvent:7231384945464">Mark Done</a>  </div></div>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <h3 class="popover-title"><b>Title :</b>group task</h3>
        <div class="popover-content"><b>Start:</b> Tue Nov 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)<br> <b>End:</b> null<br><b>created by:</b> x<br><b>Description:</b> <br> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#taskViewDialouge" class="viewEvent" id="ViewEvent:7231384945464">View</a>  <a data-toggle="modal" <a="" href="#" class="completeEvent" id="CompleteEvent:7231384945464">Mark Done</a>  </div>
```

can any one please help ? 
note : toggle works perfectly and with calendar but hide method is not working properly and i have to show only one popover at once and popover should be hidden if anywhere on the page  clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the solution of this problem.

for this we need to create a global variable  `var visiblePopover;`
now below code inside `eventAfterRender` method will hide popover on clicking the popover and open a new one

```
element.on('click', function(e) {
                // don't fall through
                e.stopPropagation();
                var $this = $(this);
                // check if the one clicked is now shown
                 if ($('.popover').hasClass('in')) {
                    // if another was showing, hide it
                   visiblePopover && visiblePopover.popover('toggle');
                    // then store the current popover
                    visiblePopover = $this;
                } else {
                    // if it was hidden, then nothing must be showing
                    visiblePopover = '';
                }
            });
```

and now to hide popover from clicking anywhere in window bellow code is required

```
// hide all popovers if any non-popover part of the body is clicked
            $(document).on('click', function () {
                visiblePopover && visiblePopover.popover('toggle');
                visiblePopover = '';
            });
```

in case if `#fullcalendar` buttons and navigations are still not working then add bellow function. -this event destroy method thanks to `#arshaw`

```
 eventDestroy: function(event, element) {
                   console.log(visiblePopover);
                    visiblePopover && visiblePopover.popover('toggle');
                visiblePopover = '';
                },
```